# How to mount mdf image, iso9660 doens't work for it?

Tags: linux, iso

I have few `.mdf` images, that can be mounted with `Alcohol 120%`, but on Linux, is that possible?

I've tried things similar to `mount -o loop -t iso9660 XX.mdf /mnt/iso`, but that doesn't work here, I got `ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try first to convert it into an iso file, with `mdf2iso` (you have to install it) like this :

```
mdf2iso your_file.mdf
```

Linux cannot mount mdf file (which is a closed format) natively.
Or, you can try to rename it into "your_file.iso" and mount it with the command you gave, but it's not working with every mdf image.

Or if you're using an X Server, you can try the software `acetoneiso` which is basically some sort of Daemon Tools / Alcohol 120% for Linux.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Acetoniso (which, in turn, uses PowerISO), but for the moment I am yet to find a Linux program that would be able to get any sense out of the MDS+MDF CD image Alcohol 52% is creating...

Comment: Perhaps one small addition: `mdf2iso` is in `AcetoneISO` on Fedora.

Answer (score 6):

There is also [FuseISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuseiso), a user space file system driver. I wish I had known about this option a few years ago because I too had been just converting them with `mdf2iso`. Since I tend to like to keep source files, this made for clutter.

Comment: Not all `.mdf` files that can be converted by `mdf2iso` can be mounted by `fuseiso`.  The [FuseISO README](https://sourceforge.net/p/fuseiso/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/) doesn't really inspire confidence in terms of its `.mdf` support.